# What is the mathematical symbol for "nothing"?

Tags: notation, foundations

The question might sound weird. But I have a situation coming up while writing a research paper. I will try to put it simply.

I want to define a random variable $X$ which takes the values from the set $\{0,1\}$. The probability of $X = 0$ is 0.4 and the probability of $X = 1$ is also 0.4. I want $X$ to take a null value with the remaining probability of $0.2$. The question is, what should be the right symbol to denote a "null value"/"nothing".

I do not want to use the symbol $\emptyset$ since it represents an empty "set".

I do not want to use any other integer say "2" or "3" or some greek symbol say "$\alpha$" or "$\tau$" since it does not reflect "nothingness" in it.

What I want to know is, Is there any **well-defined notion** of "nothingness" in mathematics and a corresponding symbol for it?

Comment: If you use the name NULL, together with an explanation of the intended meaning, it won't cause any confusion. Alternatively, make up a symbol (author's choice). In any case, to avoid confusion, you need to alert the reader as to your chosen symbol.

Comment: $\{\text{nil},0,1\}$.

Comment: For Markov processes it is usual to add a "cemetery point" to the state space (much like what you are doing) denoted by $\partial$ or $\Delta$

Comment: @quasi Yes, I agree, that is the last possible option. I just wanted to know, if there is any well-defined symbol for it, since it looks so fundamental.

Comment: "I want to define a random variable $X$ which takes the values from the set $\{0,1\}$. The probability of $X=0$ is $0.4$ and the probability of $X=1$ is also $0.4$."  Well, you just contradicted yourself.  If you want to allow $X$ to take some value other than $0$ or $1$ you should say that.  A random variable, by the usual definition, is not allowed to have "no value", though it is allowed to take values in $\{0, 1, s\}$ where $s$ is whatever symbol you choose.

Comment: I should perhaps qualify that slightly.  We do often leave a random variable undefined on a set of probability $0$: in principle we could define it arbitrarily on that set, but it would make no difference to anything we care about.  But we do not leave it undefined on a set of nonzero probability.

Comment: Yes I agree. However, consider this situation..when Pr[X=0] is at least 0.4 and $Pr[X = 1]$ is at least 0.4. Their actual probabilities sum up to 1. However, we do not know their actual probabilities. Now I want to define a new random variable by considering the probabilities that are given....for that such a situation is coming up... where I need to consider a null value for a new random variable.

Comment: The empty word $\varepsilon$ from formal languages deserves a mention here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is sufficiently rare, and handled in sufficiently many different ways, that you should always state explicitly how you're treating it. In my experience, the most common symbols are:

- $\mathsf{null}$, $\mathsf{nil}$, $\mathsf{NaN}$ or similar on the more computer-sciencey side, and
- $\perp$ or $\uparrow$ on the more logicy side.

  - Note that "$\perp$" is also used to denote *contradiction*, and "$\uparrow$" is also used as a predicate to denote "is undefined" or "doesn't halt" with "$\downarrow$" denoting "is defined"/"does halt."

But again, I'd explicitly state which you're using - although admittedly multiple of these would almost certainly make it obvious from context.

Comment: Though I am from the computer-sciencey side, I think I can use the "contradiction" symbol, since It captures "anything" other than 0 and 1.

Comment: @Inuyasha yagami. As you are from computer-sciencey, then SQL language may be is familiar to you. As I wrote in my answer it use "null" value concept and has 3-valued logic: true, false, unknown with corresponding truth tables.

Comment: @zkutch You should address that comment to Inuyasha via "@," otherwise they might not see it.

Comment: @Noah Schweber. I hope you see my thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some kind of  [Many-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-valued_logic), but you said you want to put it simply. In SQL there is 3-valued logic with "null"/"unknown", for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking of 0 and 1 as strings, there is the null (empty) string $\lambda.$

By definition, if you concatenate $$\lambda x=x\lambda=x,$$ for any string $x$ in any alphabet.

Comment: I am thinking of 0 and 1 simply as integers, not strings.